Euclidean distance for RGB signal
Source: https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/0d/44/0f/acee7e8b5d6913/US8599269.pdf
How signal can be measure by using Euclidean distance? Given by the formula like this ones:

$\text{signal}(m, n) = \sqrt{(R(m, n)^2 + G(m, n)^2 + B(m, n)^2}$

where $m,n$ is the pixel coordinate. Can anyone prove for me that the formula is true? I have never seen any formula like that?
Edit

Signal Calculation per ROI:
The signal for each ROI is calculated as the Euclidean distance of the R, G, and B Bayer channels:


$signal(m, n) = \sqrt{( R(m, n)^2 + G(m, n)^2 + B(m, n)^2 )}$


Maximum Signal Value:
The maximum signal value across all ROIs is:


$signalMax = max( signal(m, n) )$


Delta Signal Calculation:
For each ROI per Bayer channel, calculate the delta between the signal at a specific ROI and the signal at the ROI with the maximum signal:


$deltaSignal(m, n) = \sqrt{( ( R(m, n) - R(signalMax) )^2 + ( G(m, n) - G(signalMax) )^2 + ( B(m, n) - B(signalMax) )^2 )}$


Maximum Delta Signal Value:
The maximum delta signal value is:


$deltaSignalMax = max( deltaSignal(m, n) )$

Above the DSNU algorithms to calculate. Can anyone know the references for the $deltaSignal$ and $deltaSignalMax$? What is the Euclidean formula meant by calculating each RGB at each pixel and at each $signalMax$?
What the signal meant in there? I thought the color is just stand for the brightness or vignette?

This looks like a fairly specialized  computation.  What are $R,B,G$?  Data from Red Blue and Green pixels or something like that?  No guess on $ROI$.  Probably not "Return on Investment", I'm thinking.  What's a Bayer channel? Maybe someone here is clear on your notation and terminology, but you might be better off seeking a specialist.

Should say:  what you have written looks like a set of definitions.  Not sure which of those you are asking to prove and which of them we should assume from the start.

Region of interest: a set of pixels or voxels

I meant what is the meaning above their formula? I don't get it. But this is the DSNU testing on images to measure the noise. I don't know the meaning of all the formulas on this test site.

I just suggest its here: https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/0d/44/0f/acee7e8b5d6913/US8599269.pdf
